# Laravel Error : Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using larvel 4.2 and getting error : Trying to get property of non-object

Model: User.php ( thats the error line)

```
foreach(self::with('project')->where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->get() as $row)
    {
    }
```

Model: User.php ( I also have these )

```
namespace Project;

class User extends \Eloquent {

protected $table  = 'projects_users';

/**********************************************************
* Methods to use with loaded User
**********************************************************/

/**
* @return User
*/
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id')->orderBy('firstname', 'ASC');
}

/**
* @return Project
*/
public function project()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Project', 'project_id')->orderBy('name', 'ASC');
}
```

Not sure why I am getting this error? any idea?

Comment: Looks like it's because of `$user->id`. From where does `$user` come from?

Comment: public static function active_projects($all = false, $user = null)
 {

Comment: And what do you pass in as `$user`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

> The foreach construct provides an easy way to iterate over arrays. foreach works only on arrays and objects, and will issue an error when you try to use it on a variable with a different data type or an uninitialized variable.

You are trying to iterate over an error. Your query returns a boolean.

Echo your query first, to see what it returns.

From your models, it doesn't seem to be nothing wrong.

Comment: its not the foreach loop this even if I do this :

Comment: What does your query returns? What is self, it must be a model.

Comment: var_dump(self::with('project')->where('user_id', '=', $user->id)->get()); I am getting same error